# Creating dataframe columns within a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to create a data frame within a for loop.

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for sym in sorted(snapshot):
    for lp in sorted(snapshot[sym]):
        df['trader'] = lp
        df['bid'] = snapshot[sym][lp][":b"]["LUC"]["price"] if ":b" in snapshot[sym][lp] else "0"
        df['ask'] = snapshot[sym][lp][":a"]["LUC"]["price"] if ":a" in snapshot[sym][lp] else "0"

    print df
    print df['trader']
```

Printing 'df' results in `Columns: [trader, bid, ask] Index: []`

Printing 'df['trader'] results in `Series([], Name: bid, dtype: object)`

If I change the df[column headings] to assignments, everything prints fine.

I'm trying to create a df that look like this:

```
      trader     bid     ask
0     MM2        1.25    1.26
1     MM5        1.23    1.27
2     MM3        1.25    1.28
....
```

Thanks for all the help

Comment: What is `snapshot`? `Dictionary`? `Json`? Can you add sample to question?

Comment: You overwriting your column in each step..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to understand from your question what's going on and what data do you have. Hovewer from your code you overwriting your columns in each step of for loop. You could add `loc` with indices to avoid that:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
sym_len = len(snapshot[sym])
for i, sym in enumerate(sorted(snapshot)):
    for j, lp in enumerate(sorted(snapshot[sym])):
        idx = i*sym_len + j
        df.loc[idx, 'trader'] = lp
        df.loc[idx, 'bid'] = snapshot[sym][lp][":b"]["LUC"]["price"] if ":b" in snapshot[sym][lp] else "0"
        df.loc[idx, 'ask'] = snapshot[sym][lp][":a"]["LUC"]["price"] if ":a" in snapshot[sym][lp] else "0"
```

Comment: How would I be able to change the bid and ask to floats?

Comment: @Tom you could use method `astype(float)`